# Should access to controls be limited to the MainWindow class in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

In other programming languages (namely Java), I have previously created a Window in one class, and then had different classes return tabs to add to the Window, so that when parts of the window needed to updated, objects didn't have to be passed to one main class to update the controls.

However I'm new to .NET and I see that if I create a `MainWindow.xaml`, the controls are only available in its class. Is this by design, or is there a way to access the controls in another class?

Is it better to design functions so that they return the information needed to update controls, or access controls in classes where the information needed is already present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't, in fact, putting your code in the code-behind is a bad practice.

In fact, the most popular way to program for WPF is using the [MVVM pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel), a variant of MVC.

In the MVVM pattern the View contains only XAML or a very limited amount of code to perform UI operations that can't be done easily using WPF's triggers and animations.

The data to the View is provided by a ViewModel class through data binding. Data binding is provided by the framework itself and passes data back and forth without the View or the ViewModel ever knowing about the other.

Changes to the ViewModel's properties are passed to the View by the framework whenever the ViewModel notifies it through a standard interface (INotifyPropertyChanged).

The main difference with other MVC patterns is that the ViewModel is an abstraction on top of the underlying business or data model, formed specifically to make the work of the view easier.

There is no standard implementation of MVVM. The two most popular frameworks for it are [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) and [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) (my preference). MVVM Light is more lightweight while Caliburn.Micro is more opinionated but more powerful.

As a side note, the ideas behind MVVM have found their way to a few Javascript frameworks like Backbone.js and Knockout.js

Comment: Thank you for the answer and reference to the Models. Is a framework needed or does it just help?

Answer (score 2):

WPF is designed to work with bindings. You provide the form with a set of data (for example a list of customers) and bind the controls (for example a combobox which should contain the list of customers) to it.

The data itself is manipulated by functions in the form, or preferrably by a controller (a class that contains seperated logic).

Look for information on binding in WPF, and commons UI patterns such as MVVM or MVC and you'll quickly get the picture.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer. I have found a rather good video on MVVM and I think I understand a bit better now. Now, Ive created a 'ViewModel' class which contains all the data to be binded (i.e `ObservableCollection`s) which communicates with other classes to get the data. Is this correct?